# Does CommandLine.Parser support multiple occurences of an option?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-parser

How can I support this using [CommandLine.Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) ?

```
program.exe -s file1 -t file2 -t file3
```

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Unparsing). Do you need the `-t` switch two times?

Comment: @kapsiR Ha OK, as simple as backing the option with a collection. Thanks, that's what I was looking for. No I don't explicitely need -t several times.

Comment: Would be great if you mark my answer as accepted answer if it works for you 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Getting-Started#parsed-options-and-value). That's possible with an `IEnumerable`:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        args = new[] { "-s", "sourceFile", "-t", "targetFile1", "targetFile2" };

        Parser.Default.ParseArguments<MyOptions>(args).WithParsed(o =>
        {
            foreach (var target in o.Targets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(target);
            }
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class MyOptions
{
    [Option('s')]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [Option('t')]
    public IEnumerable<string> Targets { get; set; }
}
```

The cool thing is, you can even use `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` with the `CommandLine.Option` attribute.

There is also **support for multiple instances of the same option**:

```cs
args = new[] { "-s", "sourceFile", "-t", "targetFile1", "targetFile2", "-t", "targetFile3" };

Parser parser = new Parser(settings =>
{
    settings.AllowMultiInstance = true;
});

parser.ParseArguments<MyOptions>(args).WithParsed(...
```

Comment: The thing is that your answer does not solve the question as the author requested an option should be present multiple times and `-t X Y` is not the same as `-t X -t Y` which seems to fail even if the wiki states that it should work with version 2.9+.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: That's why I asked the author of the question via the comments first ;)

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same problem; it would be great to have `-t X -t A,B,C` give me an enumerable with `X,A,B,C`. Is it not possible?

Comment: @MikeB I added an example for multiple instance support 